# selenium Webdriver can't even execute the click() function

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I'm facing an issue in using Selenium WebDriver.
I'm a fully beginner in Selenium WebDriver so excuse me in advance.
I've followed step by step somme explanations by creating a simple webdriver test but it still not working.
I can say that i've added webdriver in my project.

**It seems that it's because i'm using Firefox 3.5.19 ..**. it that the reason ?
Here is my code :

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;


public class JobServe {

    /**
     * @param args
     **/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "proxyfam");
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);


        driver.get("http://www.jobserve.com.au/Homepage.aspx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[12]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[2]/span")).click();
    }

}
```

And here is the error log :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsINativeMouse.mouseMove]"  nsresult: "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/DOCUME~1/plegeard/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1872429321029396376webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js :: anonymous :: line 9839"  data: no]
Command duration or timeout: 62 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0-OpenSCG-Build-24'
Session ID: e3d70b9d-8b0e-4dca-80e0-6989d0e62497
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=3.5.19, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at JobServe.main(JobServe.java:22)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsINativeMouse.mouseMove]"  nsresult: "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/DOCUME~1/plegeard/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1872429321029396376webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js :: anonymous :: line 9839"  data: no]
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0-OpenSCG-Build-24'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/plegeard/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1872429321029396376webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:6891)
    at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/plegeard/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1872429321029396376webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:9848)
    at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/plegeard/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1872429321029396376webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:265)
    at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/plegeard/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1872429321029396376webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10421)
    at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/plegeard/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1872429321029396376webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10426)
    at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/plegeard/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1872429321029396376webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10366)
```

Does anyone could have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep inform.
I use Firefox 3.5.19 (due to working constraints)

By downgrading Selenium Webdriver from 2.32 to 2.28 it's now working...

Thks.

Answer (score 0):

Try some [Implicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and also before clicking try this

```
driver.get("http://www.jobserve.com.au/Homepage.aspx");
WebElement maybeClickable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[12]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[2]/span"))
System.out.println(maybeClickable.isEnabled());
```

Should print out `true`

If not ... then the element is probably not clickable...

Comment: Thnkas for your answer !
So it actually print out "true" I've also changed my navigator (firefox 3.6 which is supported by selenium)

And the code now look like :
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("http://www.jobserve.com.au/Homepage.aspx");
  WebElement maybeClickable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[12]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[2]/span"));
  maybeClickable.click();

But the issue and log still remains.... any other ideas ?

Comment: yes... 
and I tried String 
text = maybeClickable.getText(); System.out.print(text); and it gives me the text that contains my element.
void org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()

When i focus on the click here is a note :
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Does it mean that i did not well import my library ?

Comment: what if you try `maybeClickable.sendKeys(Keys.Enter)` - it helped me as workaround several times...

Comment: I can't even run my project due to "Enter cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: I have it maybe wrong typed, maybe its Keys.ENTER. I do type code from head. It basically means you hit "Enter" on that element

Comment: Still not working.. but thanks for your tips, will keep you in touch if i solve it